# в чем разница между laravel 5.8, laravel 6.x, laravel 7.x и какой лучше использовать

Tags: laravel

в состоит чем разница между laravel 5.8, laravel 6.x, laravel 7.x и какой лучше использовать
Обыскал интерент но не смог найти ответ
Спасибо

Comment: А что означают эти номера после laravel? Я так понимаю что это версии. Может ошибаюсь. Если это версии, а не спонтанные числа, то видимо что чем выше версия, тем она новее и у ней исправлены старые баги (...и запихнуты новые, поинтереснее).

Answer (score 0):

В первую очередь список изменений вы всегда можете найти на официальном сайте фреймворка - https://laravel.com/ 
Или их репозитории - https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md
А какую версию лучше использовать - дело индивидуальное. Но логичнее всего на свежий проект ставить последнюю версию.